# setup.exe: Bad header file: curl/curl.h haskell

Tags: haskell, darcs

I am trying to install Darcs using cabal and runhaskell and I keep coming across the error

setup.exe: Bad header file: curl/curl.h

**EDIT**
Thank you for the suggestions, I used the -f-curl and it worked

Comment: Do you have [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) installed?

Comment: What's the platform? Can you provide the output of cabal install -v?

Comment: Also, try passing `-f-curl` to not use cURL.

Comment: @Ganesh your suggestion worked, so thank you

Comment: Please don't edit the question to have `[SOLVED]` in the title. Instead, post your solution as an answer and click the check mark to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround if you have problems getting cURL to work on your platform is to use the `-f-curl` flag to `cabal` to build darcs using the slower `HTTP` library instead. This is particularly useful on Windows where installing C libraries is a nuisance.

Answer (score 1):

Would a [binary](http://darcs.net/Binaries) work for you?

We also have instructions for [building darcs under windows](http://darcs.net/BuildingUnderWindows) but it's been a while since they've been tested